# RESTEasy JAX-RS dynamic dispatching other than subresources

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

RESTEasy (JAX-RS) allows dynamic dispatching via sub-resources.  For instance:

```
POST /customers/create
{"name":"Smith","country":"jp"}
```

We can have a root resource to handle the path "/customers" with a method annotated with no HTTP method but with @Path("/create").  This method returns a resource that JAX-RS looks at to continue handling the request.  However, this resource must handle the "/customers/create" path.

I have an existing situation where different kinds of entities can be created:

```
POST /customers/create
{"name":"Smith"}

POST /locations/create
{"name":"Chicago"}
```

I would like to add the ability to create any kind of entity based on an additional property in the body of the request:

```
POST /entities/create
{"type":"customer","name":"Smith"}
```

In essence I want to forward the request to the code that handles "POST /customers/create".  I can write sub-resource locator that gets called for "POST /entities/create" and returns the Customer resource, but JAX-RS fails to dispatch the request because the Customer resource doesn't handle the path "/entities/create".  Is there a way I can change the URL to /customers/create when forwarding the request?

At this point I can't change the API to make "customers" a true subresource of "entities".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using RestEasy 3 which implements JAX-RS 2.0, then you can try to use a `ContainerRequestFilter` annotated with `@Provider @PreMatching`.

Within this Filter, you can call the `ContainerRequestContext#setRequestUri(URI)` method to change the request URI based on the content of the request, and thus, forward from to `/entities/create` to `/customers/create` or `/locations/create`. The `@PreMatching` annotation means that the Filter will be called *before* the target resource method is matched, so this is where you should be able to perform the redirect.

(You may even replace the content of the request, eg:
`{"type":"customer","name":"Smith"}` -> `{"name":"Smith"}` using the `ContainerRequestContext#getInputStream()` and `ContainerRequestContext#setInputStream(InputStream)` methods)

HTH
Xavier

Comment: Don't forget to use the resource URI. ie `setRequestUri(new Uri("/path/to/other"))`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a standard JAX-RS way to change the URL before returning a subresource. But I have a possible solution to your problem.

Define that Generic Rest Resource like this: `POST /entities/{entityType}`. Depending on the path parameter `entityType` you can decide directly what subresouce you can instantiate (e.g using a static `Map<String, Class<?>>` to hold the entity paths)